# Can UIImagePickerController be used directly on story board?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an impression that ViewController usage are similar: on story board, we drag an UIViewController onto scene, then change its class type, e.g. to UIImagePickerController. (I want to make a dedicated scene for picking images)

But later I find that `UIImagePickerController` won't work if I directly subclass:

```
class TestUIImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.delegate = self
        // self.present(self, animated: true) // either comment it out or not, both way won't work. 
    }
```

But it works only if I put an `UIViewController` on storyboard, then construct an `UIImagePickerController` programmatically:

```
class SecondTestUIImagePickerController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true)
    }
```

May I know whether I missed anything in the first usage example? And is it a must to create `UIImagePickerController` programmatically then present it via an agent view controller (UIVIewController)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.present(self, animated: true)
```

you can not `self` present `self`, use another `ViewController` to present `UIImagePickerController`

`UIImagePickerController` can be used on Story board, in your code, for example

```
class SecondTestUIImagePickerController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "ImagePickerStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let picker = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ImagePicker") as! TestUIImagePickerController
        self.present(picker, animated: true)
}
```

keep in mind that `UIImagePickerController` is subclass of `UINavigationController`

Comment: So, not all ViewControllers are equal (in terms of usage): i.e. UIViewController can be used directly by placement on Story board, but some view controller, e.g. UIImagePickerController, MUST use a proxy viewcontroller to present it. Am I right?

Comment: update my answer, init `TestUIImagePickerController`(subclass of UIImagePickerController) from storyboard